# Mamp Pro Postfix - Queues first email and sends after second email sent?

Tags: php, mamp, postfix-mta

I am using Mamp Pro with postfix and using Mandrill as the Smart host for routing.

I can send email from my local machine but only when I send a second email or run the `postqueue -f` command.

E.g if I run this command to do send a test email:

`date | mail -s test myemailaddress@gmail.com`

It does not send an email but instead it sends it to queue. So when I run the `mailq` command I get this.

```
mailq
-Queue ID- --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
97D18E1B756      170 Sun Oct 18 11:45:25  kpmacbook
                                         myemailaddress@gmail.com
```

However if I run the test email command again or I run `postqueue -f` it will send the first email that was queued and the second email.

Any ideas what is going on and how to fix?

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue and I'm looking for a solution. The first mail is queued and sends out by sending a second mail. This means emails sends out every second time.

And I'm using a smarthost as well which used to work well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was looking for a solution as you can see in my earlier comment.

The solutions in my case the solution was to start postfix manually:

```
sudo postfix start
```

Before that the mail.log showed that the first email started the postfix daemon and the second email so triggered sending of both messages.